# Help required! Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $D(p) = p^{20} - p^{18} - p^{16} - \dots - p^2 - 2$

Prove that the sum of fourth powers of all the real roots of $D(p) = 8.$

Please help.

Comment: Like...please? What have you done far, what's your own work on this?

Comment: Please show us any work you've done (even if it was wrong.)

Comment: Well.. First using descartes method of signs, and that graph is symmetrical about origin, two real roots exist with equal magnitude(I assumed that real roots exist.. Or should it be necessary to prove that too rigorously ?) . I don't know how to prove that product of all complex roots=1. Help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Real roots exists, since we have $D(0)<0$ and $D(x)>0$ for sufficiently large $|x|$.

Comment: Um.. But is there a way to prove that mod (all complex roots) =1?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: I accept that you have given a good solution. But is there any other way than checking for D(1.414) ? Thank you.

Comment: Let me ask this: How did you check $D(\sqrt 2)=0$?

Comment: I used Gp summation

Comment: OK. Maybe it has to strike that you have to substitute D(1.414) right?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have already noted, that there are exactly $2$ real roots $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$. So you are done by checking $D(\sqrt 2)=0$.

That the product of the complex roots is $1$, is then a consequence of the fact, that the product of the two real roots is equal to the constant coefficient $-2$.

Here are some thoughts how you come up with the idea that $\sqrt 2$ is a root:

We substitute $p^2=z$ and get the equation

$$z^{10}-z^9-z^8 - \dotsc - z -2=0$$

or equivalent (for $z \neq 1$, but $z=1$ is obviously no solution)

$$z^{10}-1 = z^9+z^8 + \dotsc + z +1=\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1} \Longleftrightarrow (z^{10}-1)(z-2)=0$$

So you get the solutions exactly: The nine non-trivial $10$th roots of unity and $z=2$.

The roots of $D$ are precisely the square roots of this solutions.